# HTML invert checkboxes

Tags: html

I want to have a checked checkbox behave as an unchecked checkbox, and an unchecked checkbox behave as a checked checkbox. How can this be accomplished?

Context: In my template is a for loop that creates a checkbox for each filter condition. I want to show the user that the initial setting has all checkboxes checked, and they can uncheck them to exclude certain categories. The backend uses `exclude` statements, therefore it's necessary to invert the checkboxes.

Comment: Isn't easier to just change your model true/false conditions?

Comment: `!` is your solution.

Comment: Ashad, can you give me an example in code? This is what I have right now: `<input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="places.object.exclude(placeresponse_set.response="{{answer.answer}}")"/> {{answer.answer}}
`

Comment: Bardo, the model has a table for the question, a table for possible answers to each question, and a table for user responses to each question using the answers table. Many of the answers are strings. I don't see how I could use true/false for this, but if I could I would.

Comment: use a hidden input with the name of checkbox and remove name attribute of checkbox and on checkbox change event just set the inverted value to the hidden field using jquery of JS that's it...

Answer (score 0):

Try the `checked` attribute

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
```

for more info [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

Comment: That checks the checkbox by default, but doesn't invert the behavior